# separating a column with '-' (for xml path)

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

I want to separate the 'KaliteKodu' column in my query with '-' but it doesn't work.
In the result of the query, the Quality Code will look like this for UrunID = 19241

```
ProsesID  UrunID  Miktar           Tarih            LotNo      KaliteKodu
   1       19241   216     2020-11-20 00:00:00     FHM010901    A-A1-A2
```

Query :

```
select t.ProsesID,t.UrunID,sum(t.Miktar_Ad) Miktar,t.Tarih,t.LotNo,


KaliteKodu = stuff (
(select '-' + t.KaliteKodu 
    from IT07_GerCikanMalzeme GCM2 
    INNER JOIN IT06_StokKarti SK ON GCM2.UrunID = SK.UrunID
    INNER JOIN IT06_LotM LM ON SK.LotID = LM.LotID
    inner join IT01_KaliteKodlari KK ON GCM2.KaliteID = KK.KaliteID
    where GCM2.ProsesID = 2 and convert(date,GCM2.Tarih) = convert(date,GETDATE()) AND 
    GCM2.KaliteID in (select KaliteID from IT01_KaliteKodlari where KaliteGrupID = 1 and ITActive = 1) and 
    (LM.LotNo not in  (select m.LotNo from ZKF_IT01_FinKonM m where ProsesID = 2 and m.LotNo is not null)) AND GCM2.UrunID = t.UrunID
    FOR XML PATH (''))
         , 1, 1, '')


from
(
select GCM.ProsesID,GCM.UrunID,GCM.Miktar_Ad,GCM.Tarih,LM.LotNo , KK.KaliteKodu



    from IT07_GerCikanMalzeme GCM 
    INNER JOIN IT06_StokKarti SK ON GCM.UrunID = SK.UrunID
    INNER JOIN IT06_LotM LM ON SK.LotID = LM.LotID
    inner join IT01_KaliteKodlari KK ON GCM.KaliteID = KK.KaliteID
    where GCM.ProsesID = 2 and convert(date,GCM.Tarih) = convert(date,GETDATE()) AND 
    GCM.KaliteID in (select KaliteID from IT01_KaliteKodlari where KaliteGrupID = 1 and ITActive = 1) and 
    (LM.LotNo not in  (select m.LotNo from ZKF_IT01_FinKonM m where ProsesID = 2 and m.LotNo is not null))
    --group by ProsesID,GCM.UrunID,lm.LotNo,GCM.Tarih, KK.KaliteKodu

    ) t

    group by t.ProsesID,t.UrunID,t.Tarih,t.LotNo,t.KaliteKodu
        group by t.ProsesID,t.UrunID,t.Tarih,t.LotNo,t.KaliteKodu
```

[image: RESULT]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a missed join like

```
FROM TE t2 WHERE t.ProsesID = t2.ProsesID
```

The used script

```
    --CREATE TABLE TE (ProsesID int, UrunID int, Miktar int, tarih DateTime, LotNo varchar(20), KaliteKodu varchar(3))
    --INSERT INTO TE VALUES (2, 19241, 72, '2020-11-20', 'fhm010901', 'A')
    --INSERT INTO TE VALUES (2, 19241, 72, '2020-11-20', 'fhm010901', 'A1')
    --INSERT INTO TE VALUES (2, 19241, 72, '2020-11-20', 'fhm010901', 'A2')
    --INSERT INTO TE VALUES (2, 19241, 72, '2020-11-20', 'fhm010901', 'A')


SELECT t.ProsesID, t.UrunID, t.Tarih, t.LotNo, KaliteKodu = stuff((
                SELECT '-' + t2.KaliteKodu
                FROM (select distinct t3.KaliteKodu, t3.ProsesID from TE t3 WHERE t.ProsesID = t3.ProsesID ) t2
                FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 1, '')
    FROM TE t
    GROUP BY t.ProsesID, t.UrunID, t.Tarih, t.LotNo
```

TE is equal to your code

```
from
(
select GCM.ProsesID,GCM.UrunID,GCM.Miktar_Ad,GCM.Tarih,LM.LotNo , KK.KaliteKodu
from IT07_GerCikanMalzeme GCM 
INNER JOIN IT06_StokKarti SK ON GCM.UrunID = SK.UrunID
INNER JOIN IT06_LotM LM ON SK.LotID = LM.LotID
inner join IT01_KaliteKodlari KK ON GCM.KaliteID = KK.KaliteID
where GCM.ProsesID = 2 and convert(date,GCM.Tarih) = convert(date,GETDATE()) AND 
GCM.KaliteID in (select KaliteID from IT01_KaliteKodlari where KaliteGrupID = 1 and ITActive = 1) and 
(LM.LotNo not in  (select m.LotNo from ZKF_IT01_FinKonM m where ProsesID = 2 and m.LotNo is not null))
--group by ProsesID,GCM.UrunID,lm.LotNo,GCM.Tarih, KK.KaliteKodu

) t
```

Result :

```
+----------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+
| ProsesID | UrunID | Tarih                   | LotNo     | KaliteKodu |
+----------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+
| 2        | 19241  | 2020-11-20 00:00:00.000 | fhm010901 | A-A1-A2    |
+----------+--------+-------------------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: @Emre Yıldırım : TE is equal to   t   in your code as your code is generating t from another query that is out of the subject of the question. Your problem simply can be solved by calling t twice as in the JOIN I mentioned at the beginning of my answer

Comment: can you share the code completely? Frankly I'm a little confused :(

Comment: @Emre Yıldırım wait for it, will try to extract an example from your query and edit my post

Comment: I did what you said, it worked but there is a new problem. You can see my edited post :))

Comment: @Emre Yıldırım: Please xplain the new problem, did not understand from your edit.

Comment: see the RESULT photo. 'KaliteKodu' came in the form of '-'. But not as we would like.

Comment: @Emre Yıldırım code has been updated. Replaced `FROM TE t2 WHERE t.ProsesID = t2.ProsesID` with ```FROM (select distinct t3.KaliteKodu, t3.ProsesID from TE t3 WHERE t.ProsesID = t3.ProsesID ) t2``` . check the post edit history to find the difference.

Comment: Unfortunately its given error. Could we open remote control? Is it possible?

Comment: @Emre Yıldırım I do not think the platform support this feature. What is the error given??, because with me worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224868/discussion-between-u8080-and-emre-yildirim).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL Server, you can try either of the following:

```
DECLARE @Data table ( KaliteKodu varchar(50), UrunID int );
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 'A', 19241 ), ( 'A1', 19241 ), ( 'A2', 19241 );

-- Using STRING_AGG with SQL Server 2017+ -- 
SELECT
    UrunID,
    STRING_AGG( KaliteKodu, '-' ) AS KaliteKodu
FROM @Data
WHERE
    UrunID = 19241
GROUP BY
    UrunID;

-- Pre SQL Server 2017 --
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.UrunID,
    vals.KaliteKodu
FROM @Data AS d
OUTER APPLY (
    
    SELECT STUFF (
        ( SELECT '-' + KaliteKodu AS "text()" FROM @Data x WHERE x.UrunID = d.UrunID FOR XML PATH( '' ) ),
        1,
        1,
        ''
    ) AS KaliteKodu

) AS vals
WHERE
    UrunID = 19241;
```

Both examples return:

```
+--------+------------+
| UrunID | KaliteKodu |
+--------+------------+
|  19241 | A-A1-A2    |
+--------+------------+
```